Allow just a tooltip to overflow a parent container
I've got a container with a max height that can contain many rows. When there are too many rows the container becomes scrollable. Each row has a status icon, and when hovered will display a tooltip.
However, long tooltips don't overflow the container, and make the parent container more scrollable. How can I make it so that these long tooltips can overflow the container?
I've been working with the following stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nge3zp-vk4btl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.scss

simple fix is to use the "title" attribute.  Let the browser do the work:  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp
